# no se accede a la funcion Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

Tengo una imagen en html y quiero que al pasar el mouse sobre dicha imagen se cambie una propiedad css del elemento. Dentro del html tengo lo siguiente:

**Codigo actualizado**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Practica 7</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="item album flex" >
  <div class=" cover primero" onclick="prueba()" ></div>

  <div class="vinyl open flex " id="vinilo">
    <div class="label flex">
      <div class="hole"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
...
<script  type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

y en mi fichero javascript tengo lo siguiente:

```
function prueba(){
    console.log("aa");
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta que el css funciona correctamente, al momento de ver la consola del navegador veo que me indica que `prueba`no esta definido. Porque no detecta la funcion?

**Actualizacion**
si agrego el mismo codigo dentro de una etiqueta`script`justo encima del `div` funciona perfectamente, no entiendo poque no enlaza el fichero ...

```
 <body>
 <script>
  function prueba(){
    console.log("aa");
  }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js" ></script>
<div class="item album flex" >
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuandfo agregas el atributo `defer` estas indicando que:

- La descarga del script sea asíncrona respecto del parseo del HTML
- Pero al mismo tiempo este atributo indica que el script se ejecute cuando sea encontrado y antes del evento `DOMContentLoaded`; el cual esta encargado de:

> El evento DOMContentLoaded es disparado cuando el documento HTML ha sido completamente cargado y parseado, sin esperar hojas de estilo, images y subframes para  finalizar la carga.

Entonces no parece ser la mejor opción ya que tu esperas que la función se ejecute al disparar un evento sobre un recurso multimedia representado por la etiqueta `img`

Entonces tal vez lo mas conveniente en estos casos sea:

- Quitar el atributo `defer`
- Mover la ejecución del script al final del documento HTML

**Referencias**

- [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)
- [Atributos de script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: Hola acabo de implementar lo que me has dicho, voy a actualizar el codigo, sigue el error

Comment: Si el error sigue entonces probablemente tienes mal la ruta de tu script, añade a tu pregunta tu árbol de carpetas para ver en que nivel están los archivos

Answer (score 1):

//Pudes modificar un elemento haciendo hover usando la seudoclase :hover de css,
aqui te dejo un ejemplo

```css
  html{
   text-align: center
  }

 .primero{
 margin: 0px, auto;
 display: inline
 text-align: center;
 
 }

.primero:hover{
      transition: all 2s;
      transform: rotate(360deg)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Practica 7</title>

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
  <script defer type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="item album flex" >
<div class=" cover primero" >Pon el mouse sobre mi</div>

<div class="vinyl flex" id="vinilo">
  <div class="label flex">
    <div class="hole"></div>
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias, pero lo que quiero saber es porque no funciona o porque no reconoce la funcion.

Comment: En ese caso, yo no te recomendaría usar la etiqueta onclick ya que no es muy factible a la hora de llevar tu proyecto a producción,  usa `addEventListener()` para disparar una función a la hora de hacer click sobre el elemento, si esto sigue dando error el problema debe de estar en la ruta del archivo, te recomiendo subas la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Al final encontre como hacerlo, elimine todo evento de las etiquetas html y movi todo el codigo directamente al fichero javascript. Declarando los objetos del DOM para posteriormente manipularlo:

```
const mostrar = (objeto) => {
    var a =objeto.parentNode;
    var b = a.childNodes[3].classList.add("open");
};
const ocultar = (objeto) => {
    var a =objeto.parentNode;
    var b = a.childNodes[3].classList.remove("open");
    a.createElement
};

const play = (objeto) =>{
    var a =objeto.parentNode;
    var b = a.childNodes[5].play();
    var c = documet.getElementById("cancion");
}

const KIMBABIG = document.getElementById("KIMBABIG");
KIMBABIG.onmouseover =()=> mostrar(KIMBABIG);
KIMBABIG.onmouseout =() =>ocultar(KIMBABIG);
KIMBABIG.onclick = () => play(KIMBABIG);
```

Un ejemplo de lo que tengo actualmente en el javascript con el codigo bien hecho.